# java null pointer android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've been struggling for no reason and i don't see why.
Here is my java code :

```
public class SousRubrique extends RelativeLayout {
private View sousRubriqueView;
private TextView titleTextView;
public SousRubrique(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}
public SousRubrique(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}
public SousRubrique(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

// Initialization methods

    public void init(Context context){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setSousRubriqueView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sousrubrique, this));

        bind();
    }
    public void bind(){
        setTitleTextView((TextView) sousRubriqueView.findViewById(R.id.sousRubriqueTitle));
    }
    // end

    public void setTitle(String title){
        titleTextView.setText(title);
    }
    public TextView getTitleTextView() {
        return titleTextView;
    }
    public void setTitleTextView(TextView titleTextView) {
        this.titleTextView = titleTextView;
    }
    public View getSousRubriqueView() {
        return sousRubriqueView;
    }
    public void setSousRubriqueView(View sousRubriqueView) {
        this.sousRubriqueView = sousRubriqueView;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sousRubriqueTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sous-Rubrique"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

How come Eclipse tells me there is a problem of java null pointer on the bind method ?

Comment: I know the way i ask it is a little harsh, but i've been on it like an hour long. I'm editing.

Comment: What's wrong with this @DGomez? He posted the all the code, said the error, and asked why he's getting a null pointer exception. Seems reasonable to me... maybe it was different before an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the    `sousRubriqueView` object is never initialized. That's why you are getting the `NPE`

Comment: but with setSousRubriqueView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sousrubrique, this)); in all my other classes, it initializes.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to delete the answer. did you try to clean the project?

Comment: the root should be null. Instead of pass this to the inflater pass null: inflater.inflate(R.layout.sousrubrique, null)